# Probability that a block will be confirmed in x minutes

Tags: block-interval

I know that a block usually takes 10 minutes on average to get confirmed. But what is the probability that this will happen?

I mean is there any formula that we can use to calculate the probability that a block will be confirmed in the bitcoin network within x minutes? (assuming that the resources are fixed in the whole network)

Answer (score 3):

The time T until a block is mined follows an [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).  Assuming the difficulty has properly calibrated to the network hash rate, the rate parameter for T will be λ = 1/10 per minute.  So the probability that the block is mined within t minutes is 
`P(T <= t) = 1 - exp(-t/10)`.

Comment: That reminds me, I wanted to ask you what you thought about this related question: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/43440/5406